# ¿Hay alguna forma de ingresar archivos a jupyter notebook, sin hacerlo uno por uno?

Tags: windows, csv, jupyter, importación

Quisiera saber si hay alguna manera de importar archivos csv a Jupyter notebook de una forma rápida, ya que son más de 200 archivos en una carpeta y haciéndolo uno por uno toma bastante tiempo.

Gracias por su ayuda!

Comment: para qué sistema operativo? qué has intentado?

Comment: Para windows. La verdad hace poco tiempo empecé a utilizar este software, así que no tengo mucho conocimiento sobre los códigos que podría usar. Si tienes alguna idea, te agradecería mucho.